# MM2 configuration per connector/consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

i am trying to run:

```
./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh ./config/mirror-maker.properties
```

i have following configuration:

```
clusters = A, B
connector.client.config.override.policy = All
A.bootstrap.servers = hostA1:9093, hostA2:9093
B.bootstrap.servers = hostB1:9093, hostB2:9093
A->B.enabled = true
B->A.enabled = false
A->B.topics = mytopic
A->B.rename.topics = false
A->B.replication.factor = 3
A->B.consumer.overrides.auto.offset.reset = latest
A->B.consumer.auto.offset.reset = latest
A->B.source.consumer.auto.offset.reset = latest
A->B.target.consumer.auto.offset.reset = latest
A->B.source.cluster.consumer.overrides.auto.offset.reset = latest
A->B.target.cluster.consumer.overrides.auto.offset.reset = latest
consumer.overrides.auto.offset.reset = latest
consumer.auto.offset.reset = latest
auto.offset.reset = latest

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/ssl/jsse/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/jsse/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.password=xxx
ssl.key.password=xxx
ssl.truststore.password=xxx
```

Replication works fine but i see that consumer doesn't start from latest offset but from earlieast, as you can see in configuration i tried many combinations but any doesn't work
also i would like to know how to disable renaming as i would like to migrate from old kafka-mirror

Answer (score 1):

ok so to everyone who have similar problem, it is confirmed bug, was reported/confirmed today:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10160

Answer (score 0):

KAFKA-10160 is invalid , log show   Seeking to offset 0 for partition